# How to post to a facebook page feed from external web site

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web-applications

We have a company-owned web application that should post to our company-owned facebook page.

- should be a server-to-server call
- the user in our webapplication who makes the post in the webapplication gui, should ideally not have to be a facebook admin for the facebook page.

We have a facebook App that is added to a testpage on facebook, and when I do this API call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/feed?message=MESSAGE-CONTENT&access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET`

..the answer I get back is:

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "TRACE-ID"
   }
}`

It seems like I need the `publish_pages` right, and this right require an App-review (unless users are known and assigned roles in the app), but it says in the review info from facebook, that automatically publishing is not allowed for this right.

We can save a token in database and reuse when posting to Facebook Graph API.

1. Is this impossible without a facebook user doing a Facebook login in our  webapplication?
2. Should we instead get a long-lived user token from a facebook-page-administrator, and then reuse this when posting, and re-login to facebook client side, before token expire?

Comment: You don’t need review, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to make your users admins on the page, you should definitely go with option 2: Get the token from a Facebook User who has an Admin role on the Page, then use that token to make the posts to the page. The post itself will not have any link to the original user who posted it though, but at least you'll have the content on the page.

Comment: @CBroe aha, thanks.. Although a limited number of people will use the webapp, we don't know exactly beforehand who they will be, so I guess option 1 (demanding `publish_pages') still will need review, if we go that path.

Comment: @JayNCoke thanks, seems like option 2 might be the way to go. Hopefully we can make it look as posting is from page itself, and that we can make it a smooth experience to refresh/prolong/generate new long-lived-token. Having a facebook-page-admin log into webapp to refresh, within 60 days, is not ideal, but doable I suppose..

Comment: Updated wording in question-text regarding review requirement, based on comment from CBroe.